# Drawing the Bounding Box for an element when you click it RaphaelJS

Tags: jquery, raphael

So I tried using the getBBox() method for an element/set and using the x,y,width and height properties to define a rect. However the element has a drag event attached to it, Every time the drag event is triggered, it draws a new bounding box.

I tried using element.remove after my drag function, to get rid of the element but I seem to be getting an element undefined error.

```
foo.click(function(){
    console.log(foo.getBBox());
    var herpaderp = drawBBox(foo.getBBox());
    console.log(herpaderp);
    dragsymbolsoncanvas(foo,herpaderp);
});
function dragsymbolsoncavas(foo,herpaderp){
    function dragger(){
        this.dx = this.dy = 0;
    };
    function mover(s){
        return function(dx, dy){
            if(this.data("candrag")=="true"){
                (s||this).translate(dx-this.dx,dy-this.dy);
                this.dx = dx;
                this.dy = dy;
            }
        }
    };
    foo.drag(mover(foo), dragger);
    herpaderp.remove();
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Example on JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/hu8dd/

```
var Paper = Raphael("test",500,500);
var foo = Paper.circle(100,100,50).attr({fill: "#aa5555"});

var onstart = function(){
            if(this.rect == undefined){
               var coords = this.getBBox();
               this.rect = Paper.rect(coords.x, coords.y, coords.width, coords.height)
                                .attr({fill: "none", stroke: "#aaaaaa", "stroke-width": 1});
            }else{
               this.rect.show();
            }

        };
        var onmove = function(dx,dy){
                    this.transform(this.trans+'T'+(dx)+','+(dy));
                    this.rect.transform(this.rtrans+'T'+(dx)+','+(dy));

        };
        var onend = function(){
            this.rect.hide();
            this.trans = this.transform();
            this.rtrans = this.rect.transform();
        }

        foo.drag(onmove, onstart, onend);
```